# How do you get a reference value from an unrelated table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have two tables with the following

```
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
| ID  | Value |    Create_timestamp     |
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
| 001 | A     | 2018-01-01 12:00:10.102 |
| 002 | B     | 2018-02-15 08:17:00.000 |
| 003 | C     | 2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 |
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
```

and

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+
|       Start_date        |        End_date         | PERIOD  | CODE |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 | PERIOD1 | ABCC |
| 2018-01-10 00:00:00.000 | 2018-02-08 00:00:00.000 | PERIOD2 | ABCC |
| 2018-02-08 00:00:00.000 | 2018-02-15 00:00:00.000 | PERIOD3 | DEFF |
| 2018-02-15 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-01 00:00:00.000 | PERIOD4 | EFGG |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------+
```

Is there a way to combine it so that I get the PERIOD and YEAR from the second table depending on the create_timestamp of the first table? 
i.e.

```
+-----+----------+------+
| 001 | PERIOD 1 | ABCC |
| 002 | PERIOD 4 | EFGG |
+-----+----------+------+
```

I feel like `case when` statements would be good to use here but I'm not sure how to do that since there's no way to `JOIN` without proper ids. I've written

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Value
    , CASE WHEN a.create_timestamp BETWEEN b.state_date and b.end_date THEN b.PERIOD END
    , CASE WHEN a.create_timestamp BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date THEN b.CODE END
FROM a
```

but that's where I get stuck.

I would manually create a `case when` statement and just insert the values but there's 194 rows and values encompassing multiple years and without a consistent pattern.

Comment: Hey Matthew.  Welcome to SO by the way.  Did either of the answers below help you?  If so, consider voting one up.

Comment: Personally, I would use an Apply just in case there are multiple values in the look up table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still better to do a join as opposed to case.  And you don't have to have "proper id's".  Try the following.

```
select    ts.id, ts.value, p.period, p.code
from      timeStamps ts
left join periods p on ts.create_timestamp between p.start_date and p.end_date
```

Beware though, you technically have overlapping ranges.  You can do a select top 1 subquery in a case statement, or you can do:

```
select    ts.id, ts.value, p.period, p.code
from      timeStamps ts
left join periods p 
             on ts.create_timestamp >= p.start_date 
             and ts.create_timestamp < p.end_date
```

and just have the understanding that your end date is an upper bound, but if ever actually reached, would not hit (you would need another range with the appropriate start date to hit it).

By the way, I gave a left join, which will still output a row for 003, but it will just have 'null' as the value for the referenced table.  If you really want to avoid this, do an 'inner join' instead.

Incidentally (and definitely not trying to be petty here), but the tables are not 'unrelated'.  In fact, they are very much related and that is why it is good to use the 'relational' operator 'join'.

Comment: What happens if the "unrelated" table has more than one match, Your solution would return multiple results. I would use an Apply instead. @pwilcox

Comment: Thanks so much! I can manipulate the date ranges to have proper timestamps so I will do that.
And yes, i gave insufficient data for the period table but they will encompass multiple years and a left join will do. The actual period table has the proper date ranges. 
Calling it unrelated was totally my bad. I just did not understand how to "relate" them so I called it unrelated. That's definitely my lack of knowledge there.

Comment: @MarkKram, do you mean do a "select top 1" inside of an apply?  Otherwise, an apply by itself doesn't stop multiple records.  In fact, you'd be better off with a subquery inside the main select statement so that it fails if you wrote your query wrong and got more than one result.  In either case, I would prefer to put validations on the base table to make sure dates cant overlap (perhaps a check constraint or trigger) and then not worry about this for any query depending on it.  But I think going into such detail would require the asker to post a seperate question.

Comment: @pwilcox yes that is exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

your expected output is linking the `Create_timestamp` with `Start_date`.

Example :

```
DECLARE 
    @t1 TABLE(ID INT, val VARCHAR(5),  Create_timestamp DATETIME) 

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES 
(001,'A','2018-01-01 12:00:10'),
(002,'B','2018-02-15 08:17:00'),
(003,'C','2018-03-10 00:00:00')


DECLARE 
    @t2 TABLE(Start_date DATETIME, End_date DATETIME, PERIOD VARCHAR(50), CODE VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES 
('2018-01-01 00:00:00','2018-01-10 00:00:00','PERIOD1','ABCC'),
('2018-01-10 00:00:00','2018-02-08 00:00:00','PERIOD2','ABCC'),
('2018-02-08 00:00:00','2018-02-15 00:00:00','PERIOD3','DEFF'),
('2018-02-15 00:00:00','2018-03-01 00:00:00','PERIOD4','EFGG')


SELECT t1.ID, t2.PERIOD, t2.CODE 
FROM @t1 t1
JOIN @t2 t2 ON CAST(t1.Create_timestamp AS DATE) = CAST(t2.Start_date AS DATE)
```

Comment: I'm guessing the asker would want '2018-01-03 12:00:10.102' to result in a match.  So it's not just a link to a converted Start_date.  It requires both start and end date.